# How does one handle SQL Azure Error 10929?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using several web/worker roles with SQL Azure.
Today I started receiving SQL Azure error 10929 described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx#Throttling_Limits).

The message I get is that I use 172 connections out of a maximum of 180, but the server is busy hence the request is rejected.

Any ideas on how to tackle this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of things you can do here:

1) Simply retry the logic when that error occurs

2) Federate your data across multiple SQL Azure federations (this may or may not help, depending on whether you're getting throttled at a server level or a database level)

3) Separate your data across multiple SQL Azure servers

4) Optimize your queries/indexes so that they run faster and complete sooner

5) Consider using Azure table storage instead of SQL Azure

6) Consider batching your database operations and doing them via worker roles, and having worker roles "slow down" when the SQL Azure is starting to throttle

And personal plug, use [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) to monitor open connections and number of executing transactions against your SQL Azure databases.

Comment: In the end it turned out to be a temporary overload with SQL Azure in Western Europe which caused these errors to be generated on any database access. While it is better now, I still get frequent disconnects from the database. I'm currently considering migrating to SQL Server on Azure virtual machines.